# Delete Button In CustomAdapter ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make a ToDo List App in Android. Here Is My code

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.vrishankgupta.adapter.myPkg.listClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<listClass> arr = new ArrayList<listClass>(0);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        arr.add(new listClass("Task 1",false));
        arr.add(new listClass("Task 2",true));
        arr.add(new listClass("Task 3",true));
        arr.add(new listClass("Task 4",false));
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,arr);
       final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.vishulv);
        Log.e("Task 1", arr.get(0).isActive()+"" );
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        final EditText etnew = findViewById(R.id.etNew);
        Button add = findViewById(R.id.addButn);


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(etnew.getText()==null || etnew.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    arr.add(new listClass(etnew.getText().toString(),false));
                    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,arr);
                    final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.vishulv);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    etnew.setText("");
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
package com.vrishankgupta.adapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listClass> {

ArrayList<listClass> arr;

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<listClass> arr) {
    super(context,R.layout.detail, arr);
    this.arr = new ArrayList<listClass>(0);
    this.arr.addAll(arr);

}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.detail,parent,false);
        holder.textview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.todoTaskTV);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBut);
        holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delBut);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }



    listClass task = arr.get(position);
    Log.e("Checking", position + task.getTask().toString() );
    holder.textview.setText(task.getTask());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(task.isActive());
    holder.checkBox.setTag(task);
    holder.button.setTag(task);
    notifyDataSetChanged();


    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v;
            listClass task = (listClass) cb.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Checkbox",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            task.setActive(cb.isChecked());
            Log.e("isActive Task1", arr.get(1).isActive() +"" );
        }
    });

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button im = (Button) v;
            listClass task = (listClass) im.getTag(R.id.delBut);
            arr.remove(task);
            Log.e("Del but",position + "");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Del",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Log.e("isActive Task1", arr.get(1).isActive() +"" );
    return convertView;

}
}
```

**ViewHolder Class**

```
public class ViewHolder {
TextView textview;
Button button;
CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

**listClass**

```
public class listClass {

String task;
boolean active;


public listClass(String task, boolean active) {
    this.task = task;
    this.active = active;
}


public String getTask() {
    return task;
}



public void setTask(String task) {
    this.task = task;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.vrishankgupta.adapter.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter New Task"
    android:id="@+id/etNew"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="ADD"
    android:id="@+id/addButn"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vishulv"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

**detail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="left"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/todoTaskTV"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delBut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBut"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delBut"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to remove List element on Click of Delete Button or toggle the status of task with checkBox,I'm not even seeing the Toast that is present in clickListener of Checkbox and Delete Button,there's just nothing happening, unable to figure out how to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Callback interface to solve your problem. I think this the best way what you want to achieve.

1. **OnItemClickListener**

   ```
   public class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
   private int position;


   private OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

   public OnItemClickListener(int position, OnItemClickCallback 
   onItemClickCallback) {
   this.position = position;
   this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(view, position);
      }

      public interface OnItemClickCallback {
      void onItemClicked(View view, int position);

       }
    }
   ```
2. In your adapter class

   ```
   private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;
   public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<listClass> arr, 
   OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) 
   {
    super(context,R.layout.detail, arr);
    this.arr = new ArrayList<listClass>(0);
    this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
    this.arr.addAll(arr);

      }
   ```

and

```
     holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, 
     onItemClickCallback));
```

3. In your activity

   ```
   private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback 
    onItemDeleteClickCallback = new 
     OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {

       //here you will get delete item pos

   }
   };
   ```

and

```
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, arr, 
 onItemDeleteClickCallback );
                final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.vishulv);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your adapter

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
                //checked

           Toast.makeText(getContext(),"active checkbox",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       } 
          else 
          {
                //not checked
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),"inactive checkbox",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

});
```

Comment: No, It Didn't Work